# How do I get media queries to work in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, response

I am trying to use media queries to change the font size in a certain div using the Bootstrap framework, but can't get it to change the font size.

here is the link:

http://www.jhurleydesign.com/bbw/

and here is the code:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min)  { 
    .logodiv h1 {
        font-size:36px; 
        line-height: 36px;
    } 
}
```

The wording I want to change the size of is the main heading "BLOOD BIKES WALES" in the red font at the top.

any help gratefully received

Thank You

Comment: Where are you putting that code? It should work, but it needs to be upstream of LESS processing. You couldn't use it in a static override CSS file, for example.

Comment: It's in a css file - what do you mean by upstream of LESS processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code includes a variable, which the browser doesn't know what to do with. You'll need to either use straight CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)  { 
    .logodiv h1 {
        font-size:36px; 
        line-height: 36px;
    } 
}
```

Or compile your LESS code into proper CSS.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less

http://lesscss.org/

http://lesscss.org/#-variables

Comment: Thank you - Your first suggestion works well so I will use that method as I do not understand LESS coding.